# has the %between% command in R been removed?

Tags: r

I am returning to some old code where I had used the following syntax:

```
y[df$myvar %between% c(1,100)]
```

but get the error

```
could not find function "%between%"
```

This code used to work, and I have updated R in the mean time. any thoughts?

Comment: Look at the output of `??"%between%"`. It is in `data.table` package.

Comment: There's really not enough information here. Are `y` or `df` `data.table` objects? If not, do you have any extra "home made" packages that might define this operator? Do you source any other .R files that might be implementing this operator?

Comment: @Pascal maybe convert that to a some kind of canonical answer regarding `??` and the `sos` package (upvotes guaranteed).

Comment: I suspect `data.table` had been part of your `.Rprofile` previously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Pascal pointed out, you should load the package `data.table` first:

> `library(data.table)`

Then you'll be able to use it.

Comment: What does this answer add to the comment of @Pascal?

Comment: @Jaap May be, without the `library` call, it won't work